# Why Angular doesn't get notified for native setTimeout() function

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

Suppose i have an expression {{name}} , and in the controller i write something like

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.name = "Stack Overflow";
},5000);
```

Then after 5 seconds the expression is evaluated to the string assigned. But if i write the same thing in native setTimeout(), then nothing happens Why? Any behind the scenes weird trick?

Comment: This example should work, you have watcher on `{{name}}` and if code written properly, the `name` should be updated after 5 sec. See other issues in code. FYI, `$timeout` triggers digest cycle

Comment: I suppose the problem should be in controllers, aka scopes. You welcome to post Fiddle/Plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vqFCCXhK4XDWRf6eM2Rq?p=preview

Comment: why in example you use `setTimeout` and in question is right way? fixed PLunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QpfqnMC6m5GOo1K7Styy?p=preview

Comment: @MaximShoustin in the plunker i shared i was trying to use Javascript's native setTimeout() not angular's $timeout. If your question was about not injecting $timeout before using it, then that was not my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout`: Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)).

Angular is not aware of the changes that occur after any code is executed using `setTimeout`.

`$timeout` is Angular's wrapper for `window.setTimeout`. Behind the scenes this wrapper calls the `$scope.$apply()` method for you.

You can achieve same behavior if you would call `$scope.$apply()` in `setTimeout`.

Edit:

```
// #1
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.name = 'Hola!';
}, 5000); 

// #2
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.name = 'Hola!';
    });
}, 5000);

// #3
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.name = 'Hola!';
}, 5000);
```

#1 - Angular unaware of update to $scope

#2 - Angular knows that $scope.name has changed

#3 == #2

Comment: Can you please share the code on how to do it. Please refer the plunkr i have shared.

Comment: Thanks, that gave some clarity. So without the $scope.$apply(function () { }), does Angular remains unaware of $scope changes in vanilla JS functions??

Comment: Also on a generic level what is the conclusion we can make ?